# Why does a pair of 9's split the pot with Trip 5's?

Tags: no-limit

- Player A:  9♠ A♦ (Pair of 9's)
- Player B:  5♥ 5♣ (Trip 5's)
- Player C:  J♠ K♣

Common Cards: 9♦ 2♣ Q♥ 5♦ 4♦

- Player B was all in with the smallest amount
- Player A was in with more money (bet fighting with Player C)

The software split the pot and I don't see why.

- B got 45
- A got 78

Pot was 123

To me it seems like Trip 5s should have gotten it all...

Comment: Because there was betting that happened after player B went ALL IN, the later betting formed a "side pot" that was then divided between Players A and C with all of the winnings going to Player A.

Comment: If you start the hand with $10, you can only win up to $10 from each of the other players. Anything in the pot above that is fought over by those with more money.

Comment: These "comments" should have been posted as answers

Comment: I agree.  If someone had, I would have accepted it as the answer